# Does “Install this third-party software” add the proprietary Nvidia driver or only Codecs?

Tags: system-installation, proprietary

I'm installing Ubuntu on a Dell Latitude E6520 with an Optimus configuration.

I'd like to not install the NVIDIA proprietary drivers, but I would like to get all codecs possible. However, I'm not sure what the "Install third-party software" option in the installer does.

Will I get just the codecs, or will I get drivers too?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Nvidia drivers. Those are available in the main repository but are never installed automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The "Install this third-party software" option in the Ubuntu installer installs a group of frequently used media codecs, but it does not install all possible codecs, for example codecs which are rarely used. The "Install this third-party software" option in the Ubuntu installer also does not install proprietary graphics drivers such as the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver. Open source graphics drivers are built-in by default in Ubuntu.

The proprietary Nvidia graphics driver can be installed in Ubuntu using the built-in Additional Drivers utility or from the terminal with the following commands:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install  
sudo reboot
```

The `ubuntu-drivers install` command installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies, and the Nvidia driver will also be updated automatically when an update is available.

When installing a proprietary graphics driver, it is not necessary to uninstall the open source graphics driver. The two graphics drivers can be installed alongside each other allowing the open source graphics driver to be used as a fallback alternative in case there is a problem using the proprietary graphics driver.

Answer (score -1):

Third Party software in Ubuntu enables an extra repository that allow you to download closed source softwares. By example, Nvidia doesn't provide the source code of their drivers, this is why you need to activate this third-party software repository. Third party means that Ubuntu is not responsible of the content as the binaries are build by third party users (like Nvidia).

Comment: it doesn't answer my question at all :)